# Javascript _.reduce() exercise

Tags: javascript, reduce

Please help; I'm trying to solve this problem:

Write a function that takes an array of names and congratulates them. Make sure to use _.reduce as part of the function.

input:

```
['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina']
```

output:

```
'Congratulations Steve, Sally, George, Gina!'
```

Here's what I have so far, but doesn't work:

```
var myArray = _.reduce(['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'], function(current, end) {
return 'Congratulations' + current + end;
});
```

Comment: Why should `_.reduce` work unless you're using a framework you didn't mention or your array is called `_`.

Comment: I assume _.resume() is from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce). Did you include it?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
var myArray = 'Congratulations ' + _.reduce(['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'], function(current, end) {
    return current + ', ' + end;
});

// "Congratulations Steve, Sally, George, Gina"
```

But reduce is not the most convenient tool for this, simple `join` feels more natural:

```
'Congratulations ' + ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'].join(', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, that uses all the parameters of the reduce function.

```
var people = ["Steve", "Sally", "George", "Gina"];

people.reduce(
  function(prev, curr, currIndex, array){
    if(currIndex === array.length - 1){
      return prev + curr + "!";
    } else{
      return prev + curr + ", ";
    }
  }, "Congratulations ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'].reduce(
    (a, b, i) => a + " " + b + (i <= this.length + 1 ? "," : "!"),
    "Congratulations"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go a full `reduce`:

```
['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'].reduce( function(o,n, i, a){ var e=(i===(a.length-1))?"!":","; return o+n+e; }, "Congratulations ")
```

1) you have to use "Congratulations" as the first element `reduce(f, initial)` see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

2) you have two cases: a) the last element is not reached, so append "," b) else append "!".
This is accomplished with the check of the current index to the length of the array `i===(a.length-1)`

Comment: Javascript 2015 equivalent: ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina'].reduce((o, n, i, ar) => i === (ar.length - 1) ? `${o}, ${n}!` : `${o}, ${n}`, "Congratulations")

Answer (score 0):

```
// Input data
const names = ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina']

// Do the reduce
result = names.reduce((carry, name) => {
  return carry + " " + name
}, "Congratulations") + "!"

// Print-out the result
console.log(result)  // "Congratulations Steve Sally George Gina!"
```